# ERROR on gunicorn: Can't connect to ('156.220.159.63', 8000)

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I want to link NGINX with the Django project, so made `conf/gunicorn_conf.py` file, which includes:

```
command = '/home/omnia/griphr-backend/.venv/bin/gunicorn'
pythonpath = '/home/omnia/griphr-backend'
bind = '156.220.159.63:8000'
workers = 3
```

I ran it, but got this error:
[image]

why raise this error? I am sure that the IP is correct

Comment: I suppose the IP Address _156.220.159.63_ is a public one. Normally the port 8000 is not allowed to be exposed, so you need to bind your gunicorn application locally. `bind = '127.0.0.1:8000'`. Make the same changes in your nginx configuration.

Comment: ok, thank you for your help.